# How to access the 'rank' to a template which i have assigned for sorting objects in my Django views?

Tags: django, django-views

I have created a rank attribute for the 'amount' object in my Django project views.  This is my page. [image: Bid_list page] I tried `{{ bid.rank }}` in my template.  I couldn't able to get the rank for a particular 'amount' in my template. Please help me how can i get the rank value in my page.

Here is my code:

views.page:

```
def bid_list(request):
    queryset = Bid.objects.all().order_by('amount')

    current_rank = 1
    counter = 0

    for bid in queryset:
        if counter < 1: # for first bid
            bid.rank = current_rank
        else: # for other bids
            if bid.amount == queryset[counter - 1].amount:
                # if bid and previous bid have same score,
                # give them the same rank
                    bid.rank = current_rank
            else:
                # first update the rank
                current_rank += 1
                # then assign new rank to bid
                bid.rank = current_rank
        counter += 1
    context = {
        "bid.rank" : "current_rank",
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List"
    }
    return render(request, 'bid_list.html', context)
```

bid_list.html:

```
<table cellspacing="1" id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >
<thead>
<tr> <th>User</th>
<th>amount</th>
<th>rank</th>
</tr> 

</thead>
{% for obj in object_list %}
<tbody>
<tr> <td>{{obj.user}}</td>  

<td>{{obj.amount}}</td> 

{% for bid in bid.rank %}
<td>{{bid.rank}}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr> 
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Update - 1 :

html:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
<tbody>
<tr> <td>{{obj.user}}</td>  
<td>{{obj.amount}}</td> 
<td>{{obj.rank}}</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

update 2:

```
context = {
        "queryset": queryset, 
        "title": "List"
    }

{% for bid in queryset %}
<tbody>
<tr> <td>{{bid.user}}</td>  
<td>{{bid.amount}}</td> 
<td>{{bid.rank}}</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
```

My page after updating the code - [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, you have looped through the queryset and set rank for each object.

```
for bid in queryset:
    # set bid.rank
context = {...}
return render(request, 'bid_list.html', context)
```

In the template context, you just need to pass the queryset. Don't include `'bid.rank'` - it's not possible to have a dot in the template variable, and you want the rank for every object, not just `current_rank`.

```
context = {
    "object_list": queryset, 
    "title": "List"
}
```

Then, when you loop through the objects in the queryset, you can get the rank by accessing the `rank` attribute.

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{ obj.user }}
    {{ obj.rank }}
{% endfor %}
```

You might find this less confusing if you used the same variable names in the view and the template - you make it more complicated by switching from `queryset` and `bid` to `object_list` and `obj`.

```
context = {
    "queryset": queryset, 
    "title": "List"
}

{% for bid in queryset %}
    {{ bid.user }}
    {{ bid.rank }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am able to get the rank for only one row as my updated page in the question. How can i obtain ranks for all the users?

Comment: Check that the indentation in your code is correct. If you do `return render(...)` inside the loop, then you will only set the rank for the first object before returning the response.

Answer (score 1):

In your context variable you've got:

```
    context = {
        "bid.rank" : "current_rank",
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List"
    }
```

You cannot use dots in variable names - the template renderer sees `{{ bid.rank }}` and tries to access variable `rank` in a dictionary named `bid`. Another thing - `"current_rank"` will pass the actual string (current_rank) instead of the `current_rank`'s variable contents. Change your context to:

```
    context = {
        "bid_rank" : current_rank,
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List"
    }
```

and use `{{ bid_rank }}` in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
context = {
"object_list": queryset, 
"title": "List"
}

{% for bid in object_list %}
{{ bid.user }}
{{ bid.rank }}
{% endfor %}
```